# Updating $("body").css("background") causes wpaudioplayer to refresh, for Firefox 3.6 and below

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

We have this page on which we have the standalone version of the wpaudioplayer. This is a flash file which can play mp3s.
We are using jquery 1.4.2.
On Firefox 3.6 and below whenever we execute following code the flash file is reloaded somehow.

```
$("body").css("background","url('image.jpg') repeat fixed center 0 #D8D8D8");
```

The quick fix we implemented was to create a div which fills the entire screen and change its background. So the following works without disrupting the music:

```
$("#body_wrapper").css("background","url('image.jpg') repeat fixed center 0 #D8D8D8");
```

I would like to ask if there is anything wrong with our original approach. It seems to be straight forward simple background change. Why would it create a conflict.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this is a problem with JQuery as there are lots of problems with JQuery changing elements and making flash reload. One being described in this ticket: [#4872](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4872)

As the background is being changed I would hazard a guess at this being the same problem as described in the ticket. Not much you can do about it (except your solution obviously)

EDIT:

it might be better to set up different css classes with your different backgrounds and switch the background using

```
addClass()
removeClass()
```

for example.

I'm not sure this will fix this specific problem but you should try and keep all style related information in your CSS if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll try the addClass, removeClass solution and update this thread later on today.

Comment: This did not work. In any case we still should have implemented it the way you advise, keeping style in CSS. I've also tried with jquery 1.5.2 and 1.6.2. The same problem persists.

Comment: Indeed, as I say I think its a problem with JQuery and Firefox (see the jquery ticket I linked). Was just suggesting the style thing as its best practice and it may have worked :)